# Unable to use ttf icon font in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to use an icon font with QML and so I downloaded the great [Line Awesome](https://icons8.com/line-awesome), but when I try to load the file and use it in QML it doesn't work. I am using `FontLoader` and then set the unicode string of the icon I want to the the `text` property of a `Text` element. In the code below when the text cannot interpret the unicode string (copied from the Line Awesome website) correctly.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 700
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    FontLoader{
        id: f
        source: "file:///home/user/Downloads/1.3.0/fonts/la-regular-400.ttf"
    }

    Text {
        id: name
        font.family: f.name
        text: "&#xf368;"
    }
    Button{
        anchors.right: parent.right
        onClicked: console.debug(f.status == FontLoader.Ready, f.name) // returns true and "la-regular-400"
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\uf368`?

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work too. Looks like a bug for me. Unfortunately Qt has lots of problems with fonts names. One of issues I've opened before 2 years with the similar problem still opened ...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of that makes it work reliably is:

1. Load the font using `QFontDatabase`, during application startup or at some other convenient time.
2. Use the `QFontInfo` to get the actual family name of that font *as seen by Qt*. What confuses most people is that `QFont` is a bit of a misnomer. It's not a font at all, it's just a request for a font. The actual font's information is provided by `QFontInfo`.
3. Use that family name in Qt Quick and elsewhere.

Comment: I tried that and Qt still returns `la-regular-400` as the font family but in QML nothing is still shown.